# What do multiple reports listed in a single SSRS report mean?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have one `SSRS` report like following (image)

I'm new to SSRS; what does this report mean?

> If I need to change any parameter value for this kind of report, do I need to go to every report and change the parameter for them individually?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Question:**
**What does this SSRS report mean?**

**Answer:**
Portfolio dashboard = Main report
Portfolio_XXX = all 8 are subreports.

The subreports may or may not link with the main report. To find the report link, you can right-click on the subreport (gray) then report link.

**Question:**
**Do I need to go to every report and change the parameter for them individually?**

**Answer:**
If you are changing parameter name/type and subreport are linked or use parameter to filter the data, then YES you have to change in main report and subreport.

Comment: @Hiten004, In your second answer perameter should be spelled as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your reports use same parameters then you only need to make changes onto main report, but if sub reports have their own parameters then you should change main report as well as sub reports parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to change the parameter of any `SSRS report`.

**At the design time:** When you are designing your report you can set the input parameters in report. You can provide a default value or you can leave this part if you are not willing to provide default parameters.

**At run time:** When you preview your report or view report in browser, then you can provide parameters if that reports is parametric. You can change the parameters here.

Please note that, if you have provided default parameters and you view report in browser/preview then it shows the default parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subreports if all reports are expecting the same parameters. If not is is best to go another route. I've only had to use one subreport for recent projects.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of main features of sub reports to be able to use same parameters for all of them, so most likely they are the same, but final call should be made upon complete review, including any expressions involved.   M